# how to connect to database file to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

My teacher sent me a database file, I restored it in SQL SERVER. Also he sent me a project of asp.net. He asked me to connect the database file to the project by adding connection string but i dont know where to add it.. I have to proceed the project kindly please help me.

Comment: Google ".net connect to sql server db" and I'm sure you'll find something.

Comment: You have to add it in your app.config file if its a desktop app or in web.config file if its a web app. You can use ado.net entity framework too, in this case you will be able to connect to your database by using GUI, won't need to add anything in the config file manually.

Comment: Badhon I have web.config file in my project and my teacher also asked me to add string over there. First I thought that may be there is a string query in that file and all i need to do is just replace it with the connection string from my system. But i could'nt find any thing. All I see is this piece of code in that web.config file nothing else.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Answer (score 1):

Hi You  need to add a app.config/web.config file to your project and then specifics the connection string in that file .

First you have web.config file . then you need to add a section if not present called

```
<appSettings>  
        <add key="DBConnection" value="data source=nameofserver;initial catalog=dnname ;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
</<appSettings>
```

Then you can get this key in code and connect to Db

```
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()) 
    {
        // this connection string age can be saved to config file 
        conn.ConnectionString = // read this fron config ;
        // using the code here to query the data 
    }
```

Comment: yes  I have web.config file. Can u please tell me how to add string in it of that particular database?

Comment: I m so much confuse :(

Answer (score 0):

Add a connectionStrings node inside configuration node in Web.config file.

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Replace `myServerAddress` and `myDataBase` with your data. The key here is to complete the `connectionString` attribute.